# What is the most important hardware for video conferencing? How can I improve performance on my setup?

Tags: mac, memory, graphics-card

When I use Zoom, Webex or Microsoft Teams the fans are spinning like crazy and when I try to do other stuff at the same time like share screen to present something it‘s pretty much not doable as I get a spinning rainbow ball all the time.

My 2014 27“ 5K iMac

- **CPU**: 4.0GHz QC i7 Turboboost 4.4GHz
- **RAM**: 16GB 1600MHz DDR3 SDRAM-2x8GB
- **Storage**: 512GB SSD
- **GPU**: AMD Radeon R9 M295X 4GB GDDR5

I mean it‘s an 6 year old Mac and, yes, the 2020 iMac feels snappier but I wasn‘t aware that participating in a video conference is so challenging task that my old iMac couldn’t handle it properly. I even reinstalled the OS from scratch recently but it didn’t solve the problem.

Can someone help me understand which hardware component is the most important for this use case and how to check whether I really need to get a new iMac or whether is some OS setting that plays a role here?

---

**UPDATE**: For all that claim that I need a new system. Here are screenshots of my iMac utilization during a Zoom meeting. What in the screen shots shows me that my iMac is maxed out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many people are in the meetings? Lots of video streams will mean lots of GPU and CPU usage. Perhaps people who don't need to be broadcasting video should be told or forced to turn it off? Alternatively I know at least for Zoom minimising your meeting window will drop it down to a picture-in-picture style window that only shows the main person at the time and so reduce CPU/GPU usage that way. You can further reduce demand by minimising that window to turn off video completely.

Comment: Too many video streams for the GPU to handle will also mean that the surplus streams will fall back to CPU decoding, making your system struggle that way.

Comment: Aside from the processing load… when was the last time the machine was stripped & cleaned *properly*? 6 years is a lot of dust bunnies, reducing your machine's ability to cool itself easily.

Comment: How fast is your internet connection?

Comment: I haven't seen an answer here which outlines the obvious: you're gonna have to look for the bottleneck. People can speculate and possibly be correct, but Apple has resources (like here https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/activity-monitor/actmntr43452/mac) which tell you how to monitor resource usage. The fans revving up indicate it's probably your CPU, so check your CPU usage (and if you can find it, its temperature as well). Then follow @Tetsujin 's advice and try to clean out the dust and see if that helps your thermals a bit.

Comment: @VividKraig Deleted my other answer because — honestly — you and everyone else is correct: There is another bottleneck in the system. But without knowing much about other items being run with video conferencing, I believe adding more RAM — like 32GB at least — would not hurt things. But again, I agree with what you and others have said: Video conferencing is very CPU intensive and that cannot be overcome without getting a new system.

Comment: Zoom us using a lot of CPU and no GPU at all. Make sure that hardware video decoding is enabled on the Video -> Advanced tab.

Comment: Video -> Advanced but from the screenshots I posted I don't see the heave CPU usage you're referring to..

Answer (score 2):

### Video streaming codecs in 2020 are more CPU intensive than video streaming codecs in 2014.

The [other answer posted here](https://superuser.com/a/1595107/167207) provides a decent summary, but I wanted to clarify some specifics that will make it easier to understand why a 2014 iMac is not really made for video streaming in 2020.

I believe the main reason modern video conferencing requires more CPU power is the way that HEIC/HEIF videos (aka: x265) are encoded.

With x264 — the codec used previously for DVDs and what people generically call MP4 videos — the video quality would be lower, but the core codec functions could be offloaded to the GPU on systems that had a GPU to support x264.

But x265 is video codec that is a very CPU intensive. While that seems like a negative, the main reason x265 is a widely adopted video codec is it can compress video from 2x to 10x smaller in data size which allows for quicker transmission and higher quality. Many streaming services use it for that reason. Thus an older iMac would never have the CPU power to handle x265 encoding and decoding without pushing the CPUs to the limit. I mean, even checking [the official x265 website](http://x265.org/hevc-h265/) states the following:

> “The initial version of the H.265/HEVC standard was ratified in January, 2013.”

Apple themselves [only announced HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding) and HEIF (High Efficiency Image File Format) support in macOS and iOS at their Worldwide Developer Conference in 2017](https://www.cnet.com/news/apple-answers-iphone-storage-woes-with-smaller-photos-videos/).

And even on my 2020 MacBook Air, the fans clearly kick in on video conferences if I am doing anything else in the background.

So the long and short of it? If you really are concerned about straining your system, it might be time to get a new iMac — or any other modern Mac — of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Video conferencing take up a lot of CPU power when you have to decode the video you receive or encode when screen sharing. Most of the time that work should be off loaded to the GPU but sometimes the codec for encoding/decoding the software you are using uses isn't supported by the GPU and the CPU will have to do all the work. Since it is a really old iMac I'd say your CPU is doing all the encoding/decoding and thus spinning like crazy. You'll have to upgrade to a newer system.

Comment: Please check the screenshots I posted. Where is the heave CPU usage you're referring to?